# Button not changing its position when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

What am I doing wrong here? How can I make this work? http://jsfiddle.net/qUjDa/

The button only moves if I click on the right side of the button or below it, but If I click on the button nothing happens and I want it to move like it moves when I click on the right side of it. I'm newbie with javascript so I don't how to do this right.

Here's the code:

html

```
<div class="button" id="button">
    <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=50&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:60px; height:21px; position: relative;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

css

```
.button.move{margin-left:50px;}
```

Js

```
var d = document.getElementById("button");
d.addEventListener('click',function(){
    d.className = d.className + " move";
});
```

Comment: You should consider using [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) when manipulating element classes.

Comment: everyone loves a moving button...

Answer (score 6):

Click events inside an iFrame don't bubble out of the iFrame. Regardless, you can't actually do what you're doing, putting an iframe inside a button. That's invalid. An iframe cannot exist inside a button.

You cannot use vanilla jQuery to detect when somebody interacts with a Facebook Like button. You need to use Facebooks API for that:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.0

Comment: Well.. I don't understand much of js, I have started learning it like 3 days ago. This bit of js code was given from somebody and now i'm trying to apply that to the fb button but I can't figure it out how to do this. this is driving me crazy :S can you give me a hint on how to do this? because I didn't understood much on that page you refer :\